# What is the difference between state and field?

Tags: java, terminology

Is state another name for field or is it something different?

For example:

```
private int telNumber;
```

can I say about telNumber that it is a state or it is a field?

Comment: it's a field that holds some state about the object it is in

Comment: What is a state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    private int _bar;
    private string _baz;

    public Foo(int bar, string baz)
    {
        _bar = bar;
        _baz = baz;
    }

    public void ChangeBar(int newBar)
    {
        _bar = newBar;
    }
}
```

I can create an instance of the class like this:

```
var myFoo = new Foo(3, "Qux");
```

**The *values* for _bar and _baz collectively form myFoo's *state.***

If I change _bar, like this:

```
myFoo.ChangeBar(6);
```

That means that the *state* of `myFoo` has changed, because **one or more of the fields** has changed.

Comment: so you mean that the field is the name of the holder for the value and the value itself is the state??

Comment: Yes, but the value of `_bar` is the *state* of `_bar`.  The value of both `_bar` and `_baz` are the *state* of `myFoo`.  Get it? :)  Otherwise, you could just say "the value of myFoo," which is not really accurate, because `myFoo` is an object, not a primitive like a number.

Answer (score 2):

**In layman's words:**

- No. State is not another name for a field.
- The state of an object is the combination of the values of all its fields.
- If any field gets changed, it is said that the object's state (as a whole) has changed.

Answer (score -2):

State is more of a usage pattern than a particular way to define a class's properties.  I would only consider a variable part of the State when, according to DoFactory,

State,

Allow[s] an object to *alter its behavior* when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class.

Comment: You use the term "state" in it's own definition.  That's a pretty big no-no.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the site at all.  If you would like to make such a proposal that would be fine.  Being an active member of *this* community, I'm really only concerned with the content here.  This particular answer isn't a good answer, since you're using the term you're defining, when defining it, which makes for a rather poor definition.  Consider finding a different source for a definition, if you want to cite another definition.  Personally, I'm satisfied with the other answers to this question so I don't see the need.

Comment: so you you want to define state as the combination of field inside?  My answer is the same, that the real meaning of state can only be established with supporting infrastructure that demonstrates how the variable create a Stateful behavior pattern.

Comment: It's kind of like 'what is a nail'.  If you say a nail is a longitudinal piece of metal with a sharpened point and a flattened end, nobody is going to have any idea what you talking about.  But watch somebody using a hammer and nail, they immediately understand the definition of nail.